# rails 4 foundation 5 slim-lang flash messages helper with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, helper, flash-message

I was not able to find many sources that matched my needs out there so I wanted to post this for fellow hackers to chop up and make a bit better.  The goal of this helper, was to allow both a list of messages or a single message to be passed to it.  This gave me the ability to add all active record failures when saving to the model, or just a generic message any where in my application.  I also use [rwz/nestive](https://github.com/rwz/nestive) for multiple layouts, and [slim-lang](http://slim-lang.com/) for my templates.

Let's start with my flash message partial that allows me to pass a column count to it:

```
- if flash.present?
  div[class="row"]
    div[class="large-#{column_count} columns"]
      = display_flash_messages(flash)
```

Which can be called like so:

```
= render partial: 'partials/flash_message', locals: { column_count: '12'}
```

The helper code is as follows.  Note, I also embed a fontawesome icon before the messages:

```
module FlashHelper

  DEFAULT_KEY_MATCHING = {
    alert: {
      type: 'alert',
      i_class: 'fa fa-exclamation-triangle'
    },
    notice: {
      type: 'success',
      i_class: 'fa fa-check'
    },
    info: {
      type: 'standard',
      i_class: 'fa fa-check'
    },
    secondary: {
      type: 'secondary',
      i_class: 'fa fa-check'
    },
    success: {
      type: 'success',
      i_class: 'fa fa-ban'
    },
    error: {
      type: 'alert',
      i_class: 'fa fa-exclamation-triangle'
    }
  }

  def display_flash_messages(flash)
    html_output = ''
    flash.each do |type, message|
      key = DEFAULT_KEY_MATCHING[type.to_sym]
      alert_wrapper_class = ('alert-box-multiple-wrapper' if message.is_a? Array) || 'alert-box-single-wrapper'
      html_output +=
      content_tag(:div, class: "alert-box #{key[:type]}", data: { alert: '' } ) do 
        if message.is_a? Array
          html_output_nested =
          content_tag(:ul, class: 'alert-box-list') do
            message.to_a.map do |list_message|
              content_tag(:li, list_message.humanize + '.', class: 'alert-box-li-item')
            end.reduce(:<<)
          end
        else
          html_output_nested = content_tag(:span, message.humanize + '.', class: 'alert-box-span-item')
        end
        html_output_nested = content_tag( :div, html_output_nested, class: "#{alert_wrapper_class}" )
        html_output_nested = content_tag(:i, nil, class: "#{key[:i_class]}") + html_output_nested
        html_output_nested += link_to('&times;'.html_safe, '#', class: 'close')
        html_output_nested
      end
    end
    raw(html_output)
  end
end
```

The associated SASS:

```
div.alert-box {
  .close {
    color: $app-color-code-5;
    @include opacity();
  }
  i {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    padding: 9px 6px 4px;
    line-height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0.5rem;
    color: $app-color-code-5;
    margin-top: -0.6875rem;
  }
  div.alert-box-single-wrapper {
    margin-left: 25px;
    .alert-box-span-item {
      font-size: 1em;
    }
  }
  div.alert-box-multiple-wrapper {
    ul {
      margin-left: 3.7rem;
      list-style-type: disc;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .alert-box-li-item {
      font-size: 1em;
    }
  }
}
```

In my [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) setup, I am now able to use the following.  Yes I override the default devise configuration:

```
if resource_saved
  ....
else
  # merge the ar errors together with devise
  if resource.errors.messages.values.flatten.length > 0
    flash[:error] = resource.errors.messages.values.flatten
  end
  # remove passwords from the view layer
  clean_up_passwords resource
  respond_with resource
end
```

At the end of the day, this setup builds 2 different sets of html:

```
<div class="alert-box alert data-alert">
  <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
  <div class="alert-box-multiple-wrapper">
    <ul class="alert-box-list">
      <li class="alert-box-item">The error message.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
</div>

<div class="alert-box alert data-alert">
  <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
  <div class="alert-box-single-wrapper">
    <span class="alert-box-span-item">The error message.</span>
  </div>
  <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
</div>
```

Now, all of this works, but I am wondering how others have tackled this problem.